# Comparing clipboard contents to a string with a "\n" in it -Java

Tags: java, string, clipboard

I'm reading in a txt file and then turning it into one string.
I'm having troubles checking clipboard contents against a string that contains a "\n". If the clipboard content has the line break in it it doesn't check as a match to the contents of the string. Say I copy the following:
"Hello
There"
This isn't equating to the same content already in the string. Code as follows.
Is it possible to get this to check correctly? If so how? If not is there a way I can check the text file while still assuring I keep the formatting as the \n is needed to keep the formatting for use later on.

```
            BufferedReader clipboardStorageReader = new BufferedReader(clipboardStorageFile);
            String clipboardStorageResponses = new String();

            try {
                for (String line; (line = clipboardStorageReader.readLine()) != null;){
                    if(line.contains(",,,")){
                        clipboardStorageResponses += line;
                    }else {
                        clipboardStorageResponses += line + "\n";
                        }
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(clipboardStorageResponses);
            if (clipboardStorageResponses.contains(result)) {

                System.out.println("Fail");
            }
```

I'm making a program that holds onto at least the last 50 things I've coppied for use later on. Displaying this is a JScrollPane so I can clip a GUI to put it back on the clipboard. Just trying to avoid any duplicates.

Comment: Step through this with your debugger, to find out exactly what `String` is being returned from `clipboardStorageFile`, and then modify your code to check for that.

Comment: create a simple text component e.g **jtextField** and set the clipboard content then do your **comparison**

Comment: went with Haifeng's answer completely blanked on .replace for some dumb reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove the newline character by

```
line = line.trim(); // returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.
```

Alternatively you can replace it with empty string:

```
line = line.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
```

Comment: Thanks I completely blanked on this for some reason. Did .replace on the result and got rid of the +"\n" on the clipboardStorageResponses string, instead of on the line variable as you suggested. This let me check it correctly.